# Metals and Magnets

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, magnetostatics, ferromagnetism

A metal is attracted by a magnet when placed in it's vicinity. I was wondering if it is the metal that moves towards the magnet, or is it that both the metal and magnet move towards each other? Could someone explain this?

Comment: A _ferrous_ metal attracts and is attracted by a magnet.  There are plenty of non-ferrous metal, i.e. aluminum, copper, tin, silver, platinum, etc..  These metals are not affected by a magnetic field that is not changing with respect to the metal's position.  I'm pretty sure that only cobalt, iron and nickel are ferrous by themselves.

Comment: @TimWescott [ferromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) elements ([ferrous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrous) means [containing iron](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-something-that-is-ferrous-and-something-that-is-ferromagnetic)) also include [rare earth metals like gadolinium or dysprosium](https://sciencing.com/make-rare-earth-magnets-5313780.html) at low temperatures. I would also like to note that some ferromagnetic compounds are very strong magnets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Newton's Third Law tells us that if object A exerts a force on object B then object B will exert an equal and opposite force on object A (this is required by the principle of conservation of momentum). Therefore if both the metal object and the magnet are free to move, then they will both move towards each other. Of course, if either of them is fixed in place, then only the other one will move.

Comment: While this is correct in this particular case, Newton's Third Law does not apply to all magnetic forces.

Answer (score 7):

To enlarge slightly upon gandalf61's answer, when a piece of ferromagnetic metal is placed near a magnet, it (temporarily) becomes a magnet too, and so the two magnets then attract *each other*.

Comment: More than enlarging, I would say you have completed @gandalf61's answer. Indeed, if there were no induced dipole, there would be no interaction between magnet and metal.  BTW, for the OP: interaction is not only attractive. It may be repulsive, in the presence of diamagnetic metals like copper, bismuth, silver, lead, and others.

Comment: Re, "...and so the two magnets then attract each other." That assertion could mislead a beginner physics student. Your answer tells part of the story of why there is attraction, but the equal-and-opposite-ness of that attraction is more fundamental.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, if you wish to post a better answer, please do and I'll delete mine. -NN

Comment: I wouldn't have mentioned it if you had not emphasized "_each other._" The emphasis is what makes it look as if you are trying to explain why the force felt by the two objects is equal and opposite, rather than trying to explain why they feel any force at all.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 ... and some ceramics called superconductors. No list of diamagnetics is complete without the perfect diamagnets.